# Regarding weak stationarity of integrated Gaussian Processes

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, gaussian

Suppose we have a weakly stationary Gaussian Process $X_t$ with zero mean and covariance function $K(t-s)$. Then the (mean square) derivative process $Y_t$ of $X_t$ has covariance function $-K''(t-s)$, provided $K$ is twice differentiable.

My question is, is there an analogue for (some) integral process of $X_t$ that preserves weak stationarity? In particular does there exist a process $Z_t$ such that $Z_t$ has mean square derivative $X_t$ and $Z_t$ is weak stationary? So if $Z_t$ has covariance function $C(t-s)$, then $K(t-s)=-C''(t-s)$? In general it seems like weak stationarity is not preserved. For example, consider

$K(t-s)=exp(-|t-s|)$

Assume without loss of generality that $t \geq s$, we have:

$$\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t} exp(-|t'-s'|) \,dt'ds'=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{s'} exp(-|t'-s'|) \,dt'ds'+\int_{0}^{s}\int_{s'}^{t} exp(-|t'-s'|) \,dt'ds'$$
$$=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{s'} exp(-(s'-t')) \,dt'ds'+\int_{0}^{s}\int_{s'}^{t} exp(-(t'-s')) \,dt'ds'$$

$$=\int_{0}^{s}(1-exp(-s'))ds'+\int_{0}^{s}(-exp(-(t-s'))+1) ds'$$
$$=2s-exp(-(t-s))+exp(-s)+exp(-t)-1$$

which is clearly not stationary. I feel like I'm missing something obvious because stationarity is preserved under differentiation yet doesn't seem to be under integration?

Comment: If $K''(u)$ is continuous at $u=0$, then $Z(t)=X(0)+\int_0^tX'(s)ds$ is a process what you wanted.

Comment: I think I see the intuition of what you're suggesting but I'm still not sure how to show the covariance of $Z(t)$ is stationary. $$Cov(Z(t),Z(s))=Cov(X(0)+\int_{0}^{t} X'(t') \,dt',X(0)+\int_{0}^{s} X'(s') \,ds')$$ but I'm not sure what for example what $Cov(X(0),X(0))$ or $Cov(X(0),\int_{0}^{s} X'(s') \,ds')$ are, because it seems like you need an 'indefinite integral' process $X(t)$ to be defined to calculate $X(0)$ but if you had that, why would you need $Z(t)$?

Comment: Thank you for your replication. If $ X $ is stationary and ergodic(in mean) with $ \mathsf{E}[X(t)]=0 $, then $ X(0)=-\lim\limits_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\int_0^t X^\prime(s)dsdt $.